# Sending 'MapAnnotation *__strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<MKAnnotation>'

Tags: iphone

I am getting a warning in the below mentioned line:

```
[self.mapView addAnnotation:addressAnnotation];
```

The warning is:

```
Sending 'MapAnnotation *__strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<MKAnnotation>'
```

Since I referred similar kind of posts I have to mention that, the header file of this class includes `<MKAnnotation>` and the forward declaration of `MapAnnotation` class is also available.

Please suggest.

Comment: By "this class" do you mean MapAnnotation?  For example: `@interface MapAnnotation : NSObject<MKAnnotation>`

Comment: Would you mind to be more precise on this error by showing use how you create the addressAnnotation object

Comment: Hi Niko,  Please find below the code which creates the object..                                                       `code`                                                    addressLocation = @"UnKnown";
    
addressAnnotation = [[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:(NSString *)addressLocation andCoordinate:coordinates];

Comment: Hey Anna, Thanks for the comment. I have included the <MKAnnotation> in MapAnnotation class and the warning issue got resolved.

Answer (score 38):

To get rid of the warning, you have two choices:

1. Declare the class of self (whatever that class is), in its `@interface` statement, to conform to the protocol.
2. Suppress the warning by changing this:

   `[self.mapView addAnnotation:addressAnnotation];`

   to this:

   `[self.mapView addAnnotation:(id)addressAnnotation];`

Comment: @Milad Rk I user the (id) solution to suppress a similar warning in my project, THANKS. Can you possibly explain a bit of why this works? And more about declaring the class of self. I am a n00b by the way ;).

Comment: do you know what causes this issue? Sometimes I get it and sometiems I don't/

Answer (score 0):

The solution in my case was to add "s" for addAnnotation.

```
[self.mapView addAnnotations:addressAnnotation];
```